# OGNL exp not evaluating to its value for date

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, datepicker, ognl

The below code is not printing a session date but the string itself i.e. `"%{#session.travelDate}"`.

So, the problem is why the value is not being evaluated?

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"
    name="departDate" readonly="readonly" required="required"
    value="%{#session.travelDate}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OGNL expressions don't work in HTML tags. This is the reason why you should use Struts tags.

```
<s:textfield id="datepicker"
    name="departDate" readonly="readonly" required="required"
    value="%{#session.travelDate}" />
```